# Unequal forms of the Yang-Mills equation in local coordinates

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, conventions, notation, yang-mills

I found three different expressions for the Yang-Mills equation in local coordinates:

In [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0005064): $\square A^{\beta}-\partial^{\beta}\left(\partial_{\alpha} A^{\alpha}\right)+\partial_{\alpha}\left[A^{\alpha}, A^{\beta}\right]+\left[A_{\alpha}, \partial^{\alpha} A^{\beta}\right]-\left[A_{\alpha}, \partial^{\beta} A^{\alpha}\right]+\left[A_{\alpha},\left[A^{\alpha}, A^{\beta}\right]\right]=0$

In [2](https://kvm16.pims.math.ca/DispersiveWiki/index.php?title=Yang-Mills_equations):
$\square A^{\beta}+\partial_{\beta}\left(\partial_{\alpha} A^{\alpha}\right)=\left[A_{\alpha}, \partial^{\alpha} A^{\beta}\right]+\left[A_{\alpha},\left[A^{\alpha}, A^{\beta}\right]\right]$

In [3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.00430):
$D_A^*F_A=\mathrm{d}^{*} \mathrm{~d} A+\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{~d}^{*}[A, A]-A\left\llcorner\mathrm{~d} A-\frac{1}{2} A\llcorner[A, A]\right.$

I am quite sure, that the last two are the same, only the third one is in a more mathematical language, but I think the first one has two extra terms which are not part of the other expressions. So which one is right or are they in fact the same?

Comment: The third one is the coordinate free counterpart of the first two. You should try to expand the commutators and see what you get since, maybe, some terms cancel and give you back the second one.

Comment: I think $\partial_{\alpha}\left[A^{\alpha}, A^{\beta}\right]=0$. But $\left[A_{\alpha}, \partial^{\alpha} A^{\beta}\right]-\left[A_{\alpha}, \partial^{\beta} A^{\alpha}\right]$ can't be equal to $\left[A_{\alpha}, \partial^{\alpha} A^{\beta}\right]$

Comment: Why $\partial_\alpha\left[A^\alpha, A^\beta\right]=0$? Try expanding it and applying the derivative.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that they don't commute. So $\partial_{\alpha}\left[A^{\alpha}, A^{\beta}\right]+\left[A_{\alpha}, \partial^{\alpha} A^{\beta}\right]-\left[A_{\alpha}, \partial^{\beta} A^{\alpha}\right]=A^{\alpha}(\partial_{\alpha}A^{\beta}+\partial^{\alpha}A^{\beta}-\partial^{\beta}A^{\alpha})+(-\partial_{\alpha}A^{\beta}-\partial^{\alpha}A^{\beta}+\partial^{\beta}A^{\alpha})A_{\alpha}$. So $A^{\mu}\partial_{\alpha}A^{\beta}-A^{\alpha}\partial^{\beta}A^{\alpha}-\partial_{\alpha}A^{\beta} A_{\alpha}+\partial^{\beta}A^{\alpha}A_{\alpha}$ has to vanish. But why

Comment: If this is Yang-Mills, where are the structure constants?

Comment: They are hidden in the commutators

Comment: You have too many $\beta$'s in #2 on the LHS.

Comment: Also, what does this angle mean in the third? I've seen this used for contraction, but the vector potential is a 1-form, so it makes no sense to contract by it. Looking at form orders, did you mean \wedge ($\wedge$)?

Comment: @RichardMyers I copied it form the linked paper. It should be the contraction. But this is part of my confusion.